# NodeJS App Crashing on Heroku Due To Unsupported Directory Imports

Tags: node.js, heroku

So I am simply trying to deploy my node server to Heroku cloud.  It is crashing because of the ES modules not supported issue.  The specific error I am getting is

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/app/src/routes' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /app/src/server.js
```

I am trying to import my routes directory. I have read the solutions on Stack related to this issue, and none of them are working for me.  For example inlcuding "type":"module" in my package.json, is NOT working.

What's going on? It runs perfectly locally using 'npm run dev' script.
Ironman

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "back-end",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node -r dotenv/config ./src/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config ./src/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.10",
    "@babel/node": "7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.12",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "googleapis": "^92.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "3.6.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, the solution, was to require the esm package on startup:

```
"start": "node -r esm  -r dotenv/config ./src/server.js"
```